# Error in validating Latitude and Longitude in php

Tags: php, validation

I am trying to validate latitude and longitude using a function.

This is the function I am using:

```
// Function to validate latitude
function isValidLatitude($latitude){
    if (preg_match("/^-?([1-8]?[1-9]|[1-9]0)\.{1}\d{1,6}$/", $latitude)) {
            return true;
    } else {
            return false;
    }
}
```

This is how I call it:

```
// Check for the "latitude":    
if (!empty( $_POST['geolat'])) {    
    if (isValidLatitude($_POST['geolat'])) {
        $_SESSION['geolat'] = $_POST['geolat']; 
    } else {
        $error_alert[] = "Find your location correctly";
    }       
} else {
    $error_alert[] = "You didn't find your locaiton on google map";
}
```

But its not working for me. It is always going to :

```
$error_alert[] = "Find your location correctly";
```

My `$_POST` array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [rest_location] => Colombo
    [geolat] => 6.929677319820927
    [geolng] => 79.86519121166998
    [submitted] => TRUE
)
1
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post what is going into `isValidLatitude`? In this case - `$_POST['geolat']`

Comment: I need to validate this `[geolat]` using above function.

Comment: @user3733831 Can you explain in plain words what is the latitude format? And how did you build your regexp.

Comment: @user4035, This latitude and longitude generating dynamically when user select a location. So then I need these data to store in Mysql. Before run INSERT I need to validate these data. Thats why I use above function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post value -

```
[geolat] => 6.929677319820927
```

doesn't match up against the regex that you've used.(It allows for 1 to 6 digits after decimal point)
So you can either change you regex to this -

```
^-?([1-8]?[1-9]|[1-9]0)\.{1}\d{1,20}$
                                 ^^ Changed from 6 to 20
```

**OR**

Change your `geolat` value to round upto 6 digits after decimal-

```
$_POST['geolat']) = floor($_POST['geolat']) * 1000000)/1000000
```

Comment: Kamehameha, If I use second method, should `geolat` change to '6.929677' ?

Comment: @user3733831 Yep. It will be modified.

Comment: This is how I used it `  $geolat = floor(($_POST['geolat']) * 1000000)/1000000; 
  
  if (isValidLatitude($geolat)) {
   $_SESSION['geolat'] = $_POST['geolat']; 
  }`

Comment: But `latitude` store in session like this - `[geolat] => 6.928484466599483`. its not modified.

Comment: @user3733831 That should work. But it defeats the purpose of validating. You are pasting the orignal into the session. It needs to be `$_SESSION['geolat'] = $geolat;` inside the if, when you are using the second method

Comment: You are correct. sorry its my mistake. Thank for your help.

Comment: One question. When I use modified version to latitude and longitude, will it a problem when I set the location with this modified data?

Comment: @user3733831 I have no idea. It depends on your application. Try both and see for yourselves :). I would rather go for the simpler first solution

Comment: But keep in mind that the second option (though I also prefer simpler approaches) does not test for $_POST['geolat']==='x'. This would result in latitude=0 instead of an error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Function to something like below:

```
function isValidLatitude($latitude){
    if (preg_match("/^-?([1-8]?[1-9]|[1-9]0)\.{1}\d+$/", $latitude)) {
            return true;
    } else {
            return false;
    }
}
```

ie, `{1,6}` means only 1 to 6 numbers allowed `+` means 1 or any number of  numbers allowed

Answer (score 0):

```
function isValidLatitude($latitude){
    if (preg_match("/^[-]?(([0-8]?[0-9])\.(\d+))|(90(\.0+)?);[-]?((((1[0-7][0-9])|([0-9]?[0-9]))\.(\d+))|180(\.0+)?)$/", $latitude)) {
            return true;
    } else {
            return false;
    }
}
```